# Using Get-ADUser and Select-Object is not returning specific values

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to get a Users Managers Email from AD with Powershell, so i want to enter UserA and get return AManager@domain.com.  so i can reset a user password and have it email the password to the manager specified in AD.  so, here is waht i got:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity SAMAccountName -Properties EmailAddress,Manager | Select-Object { (Get-AdUser $_.Manager -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress }
```

but, its returning it like a table format like this:

```
(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddres
------------------------------------------------------------
ManagersEmail@myDomain.com
```

So i cannot use that as a valid email, is there a way to get just the email address.  Thnaks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me if I understand what you want:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity SAMAccountName -Properties EmailAddress,Manager | %{(Get-AdUser $_.Manager -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress}
```

Comment: Great ForEach-Object, instead of a Select-Object is where its at!  Thanks again.